# Azure resources with dual region network configuration

Tags: networking, failover, azure

I'll ask this question as Azure specific, but could provide to any cloud provider ( AWS , Google Cloud , etc. )

Is it possible to design Azure networks in such a manner that a single resource is configured in multiple networks, in a primary region and a secondary region ?

So in case of DR failover scenario, the primary/secondary swap places ?

The motivation is to avoid creating distinctly named mirror resources in each region of the pair.